# Rarity function in Javascript code dont work (Create Cryptopunk NFT with Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm helping my son to create a NFT like Cryptopunks. Cryptopunks is 10.000 unique PNG characters on the ethereum blockchain. The characters are made by creating visual attributes (image format) and then use an algorithm (javascript) to randomize these attributes together to create the unique character.

I found this Github project: https://github.com/HashLips/generative-art-node and got everything to work except for the rarity function. The rarity function should make some of the visual attributes less common. The code just seems to randomize output of attributes.

These lines about the rarity function in the file: /src/config.js

```
const rarity = [
{ key: "", val: "original" },
{ key: "_r", val: "rare" },
{ key: "_sr", val: "super rare" },
];
module.exports = { layersOrder, format, rarity, defaultEdition };
```

And the rest of the code about the rarity function is in file /src/main.js.

I can't get the rarity function to work. I have tried changing the names of the PNG-files with "image_sr.png". But the original attribute print as many times as the super rare attribute.

I don't expect anyone to help because I understand it take some time to go through the file. But if anyone got time and want to try help us. Me and my son would be stoked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "the rarity function"?  In the code shown, `rarity` is an array of objects, not a function.  Can you clarify the specific problem you are observing?  As an aside... *"I understand it take some time to go through the file."* - Relevant information about the problem should be included in the question, and it's highly unlikely anybody is going to follow that link and build an entire working solution for you.  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: How you're adding `rarity` to you files? Are you using `createFiles` function ?